# Return different user name every 30 minutes PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to implement a solution for database user limit exceed problem by using a different database user every 3 minutes.

I created 4 users and the script works fine with 3 users but at the forth one, it returns the first username again and keep returning it a while.

```
<?php 
function GetUser()
{
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/dbUsers.txt';

$users = array("user1", "user2", "user3","user4");

$user = "";
$userIndex = 0;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    if (filemtime($file) < time()-100) //0.5*3600
    {    
        $userIndex = file_get_contents($file);  

        if($userIndex >4)
          $userIndex =0;

        file_put_contents($file, $userIndex + 1);
    }     
}    
else
{                
    file_put_contents($file, $userIndex);
}    

$user = $users[$userIndex];

return $user;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why using a file and file time. You said "every 30 minutes"

```
function GetUser()
{
    # static: define once on scan/compile time
    static $users = array("user1","user2","user3","user4");
    $index = intval( time() / (30*60) ) % count($users);
    return $users[$index];
}
```

Notes: `time()` returns the number of seconds since epoch (1971-01-01 0:00:00 UTC). Then I divided it by 30 minutes (30*60). The modulo operator `%` *iterates* through the user list.